# How to append element elements attribute to span based on elements class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Goal is to have three or less selections inside my h4 tag based on how many options the user clicks.

For example the h4 tag should read `'Department1, Department 2,'` if no elements are selected or have the class `active` then just have it fall back to the `default` class.

As of now I can only append 1 item to my h4 tag. I am having trouble writing this.

I have a JS Fiddle file here // http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/h5812bsc/

As you can see when you click a department it adds a class of `active` to the item which then appends the text to the h4 tag but if i select another option it removes the previous appended item and appends the new one.

In simple terms I need to concatenate two or three departments with a span tag inside my h4 tag, if no options have the class active then have it fall back to the `default` class. Not sure how i can achieve this. Some direction or tips would be helpful. Thanks

**jQuery**

```
// When user clicks on any option it will replace the text to the last selected item
// dependant on the title attribute of the anchor tag
$('.selected-options a.option-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // make the title attribute a variable for use later
    var text = $(this).attr('title');

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if ($('.selected-options a.option-btn').hasClass('active')) {

        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.toggle-this h4').empty().append(text);

    }


});
```

Comment: Two things: use `parents('h4')` or `parents('.container').find('h4')` to select your h4 instead of using the extensive `parent().parent()...` chaining. Secondly, the `empty()` function seems to be emptying the h4 first and then adding some text to it. That could be the reason why you are not seeing more than one department at a time.

Comment: What would be the departments' status when all is clicked?

Comment: i only want two or three items appended the rest would not be displayed. for example `department 1, department 2, department 3..` @fuyushimoya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('.selected-options a.option-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    // get the h4 element to use later
    var $h4Element = $(this).closest('.department').find('.toggle-this h4'),
        // create a string for tags (with default text to start)
        tags = 'Any',
        // get a reference to the buttons that are 'active'
        $activeItems = $('.selected-options a.option-btn.active')

        // check to be sure there is a selection
    if ($activeItems.length > 0) {
        //since there are active items, clear the 'tags' string
        tags = '';
        // iterate over the active items and generate the markup
        $activeItems.each(function (index, element) {
            tags += '<span>' + $(element).attr('title') + '</span>, ';
        });
        // remove trailing comma and space (after last tag)
        tags = tags.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
    }

    // insert generated html
    $h4Element.empty().append(tags);

});
```

[**See this updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5j3wg8z/2/). This always updates it only with what is active, so that the list matches the button states.

Comment: i like this update, how could i have it append a comma to each option that is appended except the first one? something like `department 1, department 2, department 3, `

Comment: Change this line `tags += '<span>'+$(ele).attr('title')+'</span>&nbsp;';` to `tags += '<span>'+$(ele).attr('title')+', </span>&nbsp;';`. @BeEasy But it will add in first one also. For this you need to use `IF` with checking `index!=0`.

Comment: @BeEasy -- I updated the answer and the fiddle link to reflect the commas, and the default state.

Comment: @BeEasy -- I added a bunch of comments into the code to help with that :)

Answer (score 3):

Some little improvements,

1. `$('.selected-options a.option-btn')` and `$(this).parent().parent()` can be stored into variables, so we don't need to find them again and again.
2. As you commented, `All` we toggle all other buttons's status, so we can add simple check to see if current item is `All`(here I use the `default` class, maybe diffent in your real web), and toggle all other elements status if we clicked `All`.
3. Then we can use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an jquery wrapped `title`s, and use [.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get) to turn it to an array. As you comments that you only want to display certain items, we can then use `length` to check if the active items are over the limit or not, and clip it if necessary.
4. Finally, we can easily use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert `array` to `string`, with the given separator.

```js
// When user clicks on any option it will replace the text to the last selected item
// dependant on the title attribute of the anchor tag

// Create references for frequently used elements, so we don't need to 
// call jquery to get them each time.
var $place = $('.department .toggle-this h4');
var $targets = $('.selected-options a.option-btn');

// Maxlimit to clip further choices.
var maxLimit = 2;
// Text to replace the clipped items.
var clippedText = '...';

$targets.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Create a ref to the jquery wrapped object, so we don't need to 
    // call `$(this)` whenever we need to use it.
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active');
    // If all is selected, toggle others.
    if ($this.hasClass('default')) {
        $targets.not('.default').toggleClass('active', $this.hasClass('active'));
    }
    
    // Get all active departments to an array.
    var actives = $targets.filter('.active').not('.default').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('title');
    }).get();
  
    // Clip the array to limit
    if (actives.length > maxLimit) {
        actives = actives.slice(0, maxLimit)
        actives[maxLimit - 1] += clippedText;
    } else if (actives.length === 0) {
       // If nothing is choose, set to default value.
        actives.push('any');
    }
    
    // Set text by join the concatenate the items in array with `, `.
    $place.text(actives.join(','));

});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.selected-options ul {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.selected-options li {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px 0;
    list-style:none;
}
.selected-options li a {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: 99%;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:3px 5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.selected-options li a.active {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="department narrow-option">
    <div class="mobile-inner toggle"> <a href="#" class="toggle-this"><h3>Department:</h3> <h4>Any</h4></a>

    </div>
    <div class="additional-info hide">
        <div class="selected-options" id="department-selections">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="All" class="option-btn default">All</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Department 1" class="option-btn">Department 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Department 2" class="option-btn">Department 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Department 3" class="option-btn">Department 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- eo // selected-options -->
    </div>
    <!-- eo // additional-info -->
</div>
<!-- eo // department -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are just close to it.

> I have added some `span` with `unique` id for each as you planed to
>   achieve this. I suggest you better to use unique `ID` or class instead
>   of `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()`.

I have added some line:

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8u01ock/3/)

```
// When user clicks on any option it will replace the text to the last selected item
// dependant on the title attribute of the anchor tag
$('.selected-options a.option-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // make the title attribute a variable for use later
    var text = $(this).attr('title');

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.toggle-this h4').append("<span id='"+text.replace(' ','')+"'> "+text+"</span>");

    } else{
        $("#"+text.replace(' ','')).remove();
    }


});
```

Comment: @BeEasy i have updated code where i have use current element `this` in condition.